React Native FlatList not rendering last item in data array when using Jest
I have been building a new app since December, and we are releasing to production soon.
My app functions as expected, and functions well. I had a couple of last tests I wanted to implement using Jest, and all was going well.
A big part of the app allows users to work through a decision tree, and I dynamically construct an array of slides based on the users answers.
This works perfectly fine, but when I run the test in Jest, the test fails, because it cannot find some components that should be defined.
My FlatList is as follows:
<FlatList
  data={[...baseSlides, ...dynamicSlides]}
  horizontal
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  pagingEnabled
  scrollEnabled={false}
  bounces={false}
  keyExtractor={item => item.index.toString()}
  viewabilityConfig={{ viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 50 }}
  ref={slidesRef}
  initialScrollIndex={currentIndex}
  renderItem={({ item }) => <View style={styles.flatListItem}>{getComponent(item)}</View>}
  removeClippedSubviews={true}
  keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
  onScrollToIndexFailed={info => {
    const wait = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500))
    wait.then(() => {
      slidesRef.current?.scrollToIndex({ index: info.index, animated: true })
    })
  }}
  getItemLayout={(_, index) => ({ length: SCREEN_WIDTH, offset: SCREEN_WIDTH * index, index })}
/>

I have added logs all over the place trying to determine what is going wrong.
But the simplest log, is I modified renderItem to be as follows:
renderItem={({ item }) => {
  console.log([...baseSlides, ...dynamicSlides])
  console.log(item)
  return <View style={styles.flatListItem}>{getComponent(item)}</View>
}}

The result of console.log([...baseSlides, ...dynamicSlides]) is exactly as I expect, it contains all items that should be there.
But, console.log(item) never logs the last item in the array.
I appreciate this may not be enough code to go off, but there is so much code involved with this part of the app I simply don't know what to share. I am hoping I am maybe overlooking something extremely simple.
Thanks
